# Unable to uninstall or update Angular CLI from Mac

Tags: angular

I have the following versions currently installed

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.9
Node: 17.4.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.9
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.9
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.9
@schematics/angular          9.1.9
@schematics/update           0.901.9
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

Since I was not able to update angular-cli (ng update), I tried uninstalling it using

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm cache verify --force
```

These commands reported no issues and appeared to have executed just fine.  However, if I issue `ng version` after issuing these commands, I still get my old versions like shown above.

None of the answers on Stackoverflow on Google helped, I read probably 50 of them.

Attempt to update also fails with

```
sudo ng update

The "@angular-devkit/schematics" package cannot be resolved from the workspace root directory. This may be due to an unsupported node modules structure.
Please remove both the "node_modules" directory and the package lock file; and then reinstall.
If this does not correct the problem, please temporarily install the "@angular-devkit/schematics" package within the workspace. It can be removed once the update is complete.
```

I am not inside any project folder so I don't understand why it complains about the node_modules directory or package-lock file.

I am on Mac BigSur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the posts I found worked no matter what I did.  And Angular github was useless like in most cases.

Eventually, I have up on uninstalling or updating Angular CLI as none of solutions I found worked.  I instead decided to uninstal node from my Mac and reinstall it.

To completely uninstall node, I followed this post
https://www.positronx.io/how-to-uninstall-node-js-and-npm-from-macos/

Once I uninstalled node, `ng version` no longer was reporting any angular so all good.  Then I downloaded latest node and installed it on my Mac.  After this I simply issued command to install angular like:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After this, my Angular was on version 13.x